# Converting an integer to a boxed enum type only known at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums

Imagine we have an enum:

```
enum Foo { A=1,B=2,C=3 }
```

If the type is known at compile-time, a direct cast can be used to change between the enum-type and the underlying type (usually `int`):

```
static int GetValue() { return 2; }
...
Foo foo = (Foo)GetValue(); // becomes Foo.B
```

And boxing this gives a box of type `Foo`:

```
object o1 = foo;
Console.WriteLine(o1.GetType().Name); // writes Foo
```

(and indeed, you can box as `Foo` and unbox as `int`, or box as `int` and unbox as `Foo` quite happily)

***However*** (the problem); if the enum type is only known at runtime things are... trickier. It is obviously trivial to box it as an `int` - but can I box it as `Foo`? (Ideally without using generics and `MakeGenericMethod`, which would be ugly). `Convert.ChangeType` throws an exception. `ToString` and `Enum.Parse` works, but is *horribly* inefficient.

I could look at the defined values (`Enum.GetValues` or `Type.GetFields`), but that is very hard for `[Flags]`, and even without would require getting back to the underlying-type first (which isn't as hard, thankfully).

But; is there a more direct to get from a value of the correct underlying-type to a box of the enum-type, where the type is only known at runtime?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I think the `Enum.ToObject` method will do what you want.

```
Type type= typeof(Foo);
object o1 = Enum.ToObject(type,GetValue());
```

Comment: Easy to miss. Seems like a terrible method name. Something like `Enum.FromValue` may have been better.

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted to add something to [@aaronb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660194/converting-an-integer-to-a-boxed-enum-type-only-known-at-runtime/2660215#2660215): I had to do this very thing for some auto-mapping code and found out that I needed to do several checks in order to make the code work for arbitrary types.  In particular, null values and nullable enums will give you headaches.

The most foolproof code I have at the moment is this:

```
static object CastBoxedValue(object value, Type destType)
{
    if (value == null)
        return value;

    Type enumType = GetEnumType(destType);
    if (enumType != null)
        return Enum.ToObject(enumType, value);

    return value;
}

private static Type GetEnumType(Type type)
{
    if (type.IsEnum)
        return type;

    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        var genericDef = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        if (genericDef == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            var genericArgs = type.GetGenericArguments();
            return (genericArgs[0].IsEnum) ? genericArgs[0] : null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you can never have a nullable type then just ignore this. :)

Comment: Valuable thoughts, but indeed I've already stripped out things like `Nullable<T>`, `List<T>` etc upstream of this.

Comment: `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` might be a little more straightforward than inspecting the generic arguments.